# For Loops with Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def divisible_by_7(lst: List[int]) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if lst contains an element divisible
    by 7. Otherwise, return False.

    >>> divisible_by_7([4,8,21,6])
    True
    >>> divisible_by_7([1,2,8,9])
    False
    """
    for num in lst:
        if num % 7 == 0:
            return True
        return False
```

When I run this function, it will only execute once. How can I instead verify all values in the list and see if they are True or False so it properly follows how `for` loops function without using the built-in `any` function?

Comment: Dedent `return False`?

Comment: Malicious compliance: `return not all(num % 7 != 0 for num in lst)`

Comment: `return not all(num % 7 for num in lst)`

Answer (score 2):

```py
    def divisible_by_7(self, lst):
        """Return True if and only if lst contains an element divisible
        by 7. Otherwise, return False.

        >>> divisible_by_7([4,8,21,6])
        True
        >>> divisible_by_7([1,2,8,9])
        False
        """
        for num in lst:
            if num % 7 == 0:
                return True
        return False
```

Put your return False statement outside of the for-loop. Return True iff there is an element in the list that is divisible by 7 and return False as default.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no if check for `return False` if it grabs no `if num % 7 == 0` it returns False in any iteration, you should dedent `return False` as @jonrsharpe commented. Yet, you can have the following code.

**Code**

```
def divisible_by_7(lst: list) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if lst contains an element divisible
    by 7. Otherwise, return False.

    >>> divisible_by_7([4,8,21,6])
    True
    >>> divisible_by_7([1,2,8,9])
    False
    """
    return any([num%7 == 0 for num in lst])
```

**Output**

```
>>> divisible_by_7([4,8,21,6])
True
>>> divisible_by_7([1,2,8,9])
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`for-else`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) loop

**Ex.**

```
def divisible_by_7(lst: list) -> bool:
    for num in lst:
        if num % 7 == 0:
            return True
    else:
        return False

lst = [4,8,21,6]
lst1 = [1,2,8,9]
print(divisible_by_7(lst))
print(divisible_by_7(lst1))

True
False
```